# How to add word news letter document in the body of the email using Java?

Tags: java, newsletter

I am trying to send a news letter which would includes images and links.  I have the template designed in the word document format.  Is there a way that I could attach this word document in the body of the email with the contents using Java mail?

Comment: Do you want the Word document **attached** or **embedded**?  The two are different, & while the first is easy, I doubt the email format allows **embedding** a Word document.  If you want styled text in an email, use HTML formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of email with attachment: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=30251

BTW if you ask me I'd recommend you to send email without attachment but make your email body to look like template you have. To do this open your template using MS word, then save it as HTML file. Now you have HTML template. Open and discover it. I am sure I will find where to insert your text. You can implement a sort of simple template engine yourself (by replacing some kind of marks by real text) or use ready template engines (like velocity.) As a result you can generate good looking email with pictures etc and without attachments. Remember: only 10% of your recipient will open your email and only 10% of them will open the attachment.